# Reading user input causes "TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a game where each player takes away 1-3 chips per turn, and the person who takes the last chip wins.  At the part where the player is asked to chose an amount of chips to take, I get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\DOwnloads\okay (1).py", line 56, in <module>
    temp = input(int ("there are", chips,"chips. how many chips does player one want to take"))
TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Here is the code:

```
chips  = 21
MAXCHIPS= 3
MINCHIPS= 1

playerOne = " "
playerTwo = " "

score1 = 0
TIE = "it was a tie"
score2 = 0
INTRO = "do you know how to play takeaways? please enter either yes or no"
RULES = "you each take turns to remove 1-3 chips from a pileof 21. whoever      takes the last chip from the pile wins the round"



while(True):
        instructions=input(INTRO)
        if ((instructions == "yes") or (instructions == "no")):
        if (instructions == "no"):
               print (RULES)
              break
            elif (instructions == "yes"):
                break

while( True ):
        temp=input("what is player ones name? please enter a one word name")

        if (temp.isalpha()) :
                temp=playerOne
                break

while( True ):
        temp=input("what is player twos name? please enter a one word name")
        if (temp.isalpha()) :
             temp=playerTwo
            break
while( True ):
    game = input("How many gammes do  you want to play?")
    if( game.isdigit() ):
        game = int(game)
    if( game > 0 )and (game < 10):
        break


while( True):
    chips = int(chips)
    temp = input(int ("there are", chips,"chips. how many chips does player one want to take"))
    if (temp.isdigit() ):
            temp = int(temp)
            chips=-temp
            break
```

Comment: I think the int should be out side

Comment: The `int` in the input line is unnecessary as temp is converted to an int in the conditional.

Comment: The code you posted is indented wrong in multiple places.  (For example, look at the first two `if` statements --- the second should be to the right of the first.)  I can't guess exactly what you intended, so please edit your post to fix the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You have `input(int("input string"))` when you need `int(input("input string"))`

Change this line:

```
temp = input(int ("there are", chips,"chips. how many chips does player one want to take"))
```

To this:

```
temp = int(input("there are", chips,"chips. how many chips does player one want to take"))
```